# How to set the user to current_user when creating a new model using rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I have a rails 3.0.10 project I'm building using the rails_admin gem to some basic administrative functions. For one of the models being managed in rails_admin, I'd like to be able to set the user association based on the current_user. I would think this should be a fairly common requirement, so I'm sure that I'm missing something obvious.

I did find one post that seemed to solve this, but it's not working for me. So I was hoping someone else out there might have another suggestion.

This is the conversation I was able to find: http://groups.google.com/group/rails_admin/browse_thread/thread/ce0e22aeec1f72b7

Comment: did you find the solution? I am stuck with this issue. I would like to use current user id for "created_by" field in another table when creating new record. Also, I dont want to display the field Created By on the form, even hidden field.

Comment: I don't think I ever did find a solution to this. I ended up switching admin gems to activeadmin for a number of different reasons and I think I was able to get that gem to handle this situation. Let me dig through my notes and find out for sure and I can post an answer here in the near future.

Comment: It doesn't look like I am doing anything like that right now - the project I had been working on that prompted this question has been idle for quite some time. Sorry! I'm hoping to start back into this app in the near future and if/when I find a solution, I'll post it here. If you find one first, I'd love to see it as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anyone is still interested, there is an workaround for this on Rails Admin's wike page:
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/How-to-set-default-values

```
config.model Post do 
  edit do 
    field :user_id, :hidden do
      default_value do
        bindings[:view]._current_user.id
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: This only hides the field and sets the default value, but this default value can be overriden in POST request which means it is not secure.